# scss not render to css in bootstrap 5 sass

Tags: django, sass, bootstrap-5

I work on a project of Django with bootstrap 5 sass

when I run my project, CSS effects do not apply.
then I tried to (npm run scss) to discover the problem

i got this error message:

```
Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\10\Desktop\Projects\Markvira\static\css\base.css'
```

This is My project Files:

base.html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Markvira</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="{% static 'images/base/favicon.ico' %}"/>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static './css/base.css' %}">
     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <!------>
    <!--Navbar-->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!--Navbar-->
    <!----->    
    <main>
        {% block content %}


        {% endblock %}
    </main>
    <footer>
        
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "scss": "node-sass --watch ./static/scss/base.scss -o ./static/css"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta3",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

base.scss

```
@import "custom_bootstrap";
@import "navbar";

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

[project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQGTN.png)

can you help in the following:

1. why base.css file does not show effects in my website?
2. should i after installing (npm i bootstrap@next) to include links by jsDelivr, because i noticed some effects did not show till i include jsDelivr bootstrap links?

Thank you

Comment: Try using the Dart Sass as node-sass has been deprecated.

Comment: I tried using Dart
and now I have two notes: 1) After setting up Dart sass using Chocolately. i did not find  sass in dependencies in package.json file.. so i added them manually... 2) files go ok but when i try to import and scss file into the main scss file...i got always an error message "can't find stylesheet to import"